# Why I cannot getting the output I expect in C programming?

Tags: c

When I run the code I get a crappy output page. My goal is to find the process I took in the picture.

[image: empty output]]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>

int i,n,j;

int faktoriyel(int fak)
{

fak =1;
printf("n degerini giriniz : ");
scanf("%d", &n);
for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
    fak*=i;
}
return fak;
}

int main()
{
int toplam = 0;
int y;

for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
{   
    y = (j + (n-j/faktoriyel(j)));
    toplam+=y;
    printf("%d toplamidir ", toplam);
}    
}
```

I need to find this calculation.

[image: that calculation]]

Comment: Keep in mind that SO is not a code review website. I suggest you to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, for this question, using a debugger in order to see what your code do step by step would probably help you understand your code better and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: In the expression `(n-j/faktoriyel(j))`, you need to put `()` around `n-j`.

Comment: Also: your expression `(n-j/faktoriyel(j))` will be done using integer division (since all are `int`s. i think you need to use floating point division (by casting to `float`/`double` or chaning the types of the variables.

Comment: One final thing: why are `i,n,j` declared global ? You can replace them with local variables in each function. And your `n` is uninitialized when you first use it.

Comment: yes, it gives me integer devision.  How could I get float answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The `n` value is 0 initially, means that it i not initialized. That's why the `for(j=1; j<=n; j++)` loop cannot proceed. You must init the `n` value before that loop not in the `faktoriyel` function. So the main code should be like this:

```c
int main()
{
int toplam = 0;
int y;

printf("n degerini giriniz : ");
scanf("%d", &n);

for(j=1; j<=n; j++)
{   
    y = (j + (n-j/faktoriyel(j)));
    toplam+=y;
    printf("%d toplamidir ", toplam);
}    
}
```